# Adding image control box into excel cells as template

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to add picture box into the excel cells, so the user could click the box on the cell and insert image instead of clicking the add picture tool at the top of excel?

example of outcome: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X93nL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this code:

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .ButtonName = "Submit"
    .Title = "Select an image file"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "JPG", "*.JPG"
    .Filters.Add "JPEG File Interchange Format", "*.JPEG"
    .Filters.Add "Graphics Interchange Format", "*.GIF"
    .Filters.Add "Portable Network Graphics", "*.PNG"
    .Filters.Add "Tag Image File Format", "*.TIFF"
    .Filters.Add "All Pictures", "*.*"

    If .Show = -1 Then
        Dim img As Object
        Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(.SelectedItems(1))

    End If
End With
```

Embed the code onto a click event for an object in your worksheet (e.g. ActiveX / Form).
Please Note: The solution is from the user Portland Runner: [Excel VBA - Insert image (using dialog box) into a certain cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355537/excel-vba-insert-image-using-dialog-box-into-a-certain-cell).

After all, the add value is rather low. You need to save the file as an .xlsm in order to keep the code working.